# executor Service multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I have used `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` in my application. This is a static variable.

The `corePoolsize` is 10 threads. Suppose all the 10 thread is currently running with a task assigned. I would like to know what will happen if I create one more task and try to run it.

I tried in my system but what I see is the task is running without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you submit a new task when all the threads are currently active, it will be added to a queue in a FIFO manner and will be processed when one thread becomes available. This queue is unbounded so the maximum elements it can hold is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

This is answered in the Javadoc for [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-):

> If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available. If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.

Comment: I guess; even with Integer.MAX_VALUE number of tasks the waiting queue will not be fully loaded, as multiple processors would take up the tasks and divide among themselves.

Comment: As I've commented on your answer, this makes the assumption that jobs are completed faster than they are submitted

Comment: @MrWiggles Which other answer? And why does it makes that assumption? If jobs are not completed faster that they are submitted, they are added to a queue, which what I'm saying.

Comment: Sorry - not your answer - @AnirbanDebnaths answer

Answer (score 1):

Taken directly from the Javadoc

> If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available

Answer (score -1):

Javadoc

> At any point, at most "nThreads" threads will be active processing tasks.

May be any of your previously executing task got terminated due to some exception.

Comment: This in no way answers the OPs question.  They specifically want to know what happens when all 10 threads are busy and you submit another task

Comment: @MrWiggles - but the data she provided is incorrect, how can be additional task start their execution if already 10 threads are executing.

Comment: Please see the other answers, they explain precisely what happens

Answer (score -1):

Your system normally has multiple processors.
That's why you are unable to see any difference.

Even if you mention the thread pool as 10, the threads are actually being evenly distributed to all the processors in the system by the JVM.
Thus the queue that is used to store the upcoming tasks are never full with just 10 threads.

I guess; even with Integer.MAX_VALUE number of tasks the waiting queue will not be fully loaded, as multiple processors would take up the tasks and divide among themselves.

Comment: What if new jobs are submitted faster than they can be completed?

Comment: @Rashmi must be sending low load tasks thats why she is unable to see any difference.